# railsにおいてgemがインストールできない（ERROR: Error installing byebug: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.）

Tags: ruby-on-rails

`gem install byebug -v '11.1.3' --source 'https://rubygems.org/'`を実行したところ以下のようなエラーが出てきます。

```
ERROR:  Error installing byebug:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    current directory: /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
/home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/bin/ruby -I /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/2.7.0 -r ./siteconf20200607-10292-48tqbx.rb extconf.rb
creating Makefile

current directory: /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" clean

current directory: /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR="
compiling breakpoint.c
compiling byebug.c
compiling context.c
compiling locker.c
compiling threads.c
linking shared-object byebug/byebug.so

current directory: /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3/ext/byebug
make "DESTDIR=" install
/usr/bin/install -c -m 0755 byebug.so ./.gem.20200607-10292-1pvedcx/byebug

Permission denied @ rb_file_s_rename - (./.gem.20200607-10292-1pvedcx/byebug, /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/byebug)

Gem files will remain installed in /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/byebug-11.1.3 for inspection.
Results logged to /home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/gem_make.out
```

解決策が分からないので教えて頂きたいです。

環境
・windows10
.ruby 2.7.0
.rails 6.0.3.1

Comment: ```/home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/byebug```にある```gem_make.out```のユーザーに実行権限を付与することで無事インストールすることができました。

Answer (score 2):

`/home/tarou/.rbenv/versions/2.7.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.7.0/byebug-11.1.3/byebug`にある
`gem_make.out`に実行権限を付与することで無事インストールすることができました。